# What is the best practive in bazel to overwrite the copts of an external dependency?

Tags: c++, bazel

Suppose I have a `workspace(name == "foo")` who requires an external lib **"bar"**.

In the workspace I declair a `cc_binary(name = "baz", deps = ["@bar"])`.

**"bar"** is a static library (".lib" on Windows or ".a" on Linux), but I want to compile `bar.a` with the same `copts` as **"baz"**. For example on Windows, one may want to use `/Qspectre` flags or `/D_UNICODE` to compile `baz.lib`.

One way is to overwrite `--copts` in `.bazelrc` file or command line, but it will apply to all targets.

Another possible way is to use a new `BUILD` file for **"bar"**, but I wonder what's the best practice to do so?

Comment: FYI: When there are conflicting options the compiler applies the last to appear on the command line. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiling-a-c-cpp-program?view=msvc-170): *Compiler options are processed "left to right," and when a conflict is detected, the last (rightmost) option wins.* From that I'd look into **appending** all `baz` options to `bar`. Perhaps simpler than **overwriting** copts.